# Bounded set absolute value of the difference

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq\mathbb R$.
Prove that $$
\sup(\left\{ \,\left|x-y\right|\;:\;x,y\in A\,\right\})=\sup A-\inf A$$
and prove the following as the first step:
$$\sup(\left\{ \,\left|x-y\right|\;:\;x,y\in A\,\right\})=\sup(\left\{ \,x-y\;:\;x,y\in A\,\right\}).
$$
I've tried proving the assumption using the strict definition of the supremum, but all I could do is prove the assumption without the needed "first step". any idea on how to do that?

Comment: I edited your question. Please just use math mode for equations and math symbols.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\sup\limits_{\{(x,y)\in A^2\}}\vert x-y\vert= \sup\limits_{\{(x,y)\in A^2 \mid x \ge y\}}(x-y)= \sup\limits_{\{(x,y)\in A^2\}}(x-y)$$

for the first step.

And

$$x-y \le \sup A -\inf A$$ for any $(x,y) \in A^2$ for the conclusion.

Comment: I don't get it, how's that a hint?

Comment: The first equality is the most important. For any $x,y$ $\vert x-y\vert =\sup(x-y,y-x)$ which enables to get rid of the absolute value.

Comment: Sure, but that's part of what we must prove in this question

Comment: Is this not evident as by definition $\vert x - y \vert = x-y$ if $x \ge y$ and $\vert x - y \vert =y-x$ when $x \le y$?